# Conditional Iteration over a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I am trying to loop through over a pandas data frame to meet specific conditions in an optimization task.

> Let me provide some backgrounds and what I have done so far.

So the table below is my sample of the top 10 rows of my input data (named `df_long`) after loading and melting using pandas. I have 150 rows in my actual dataset.

```
   Hour TypeofTask TaskFrequency  TotalTaskatSpecific Hour
0   08    A             5         50
1   09    D             8         30
2   08    D             7         50
3   10    C             4         20
4   09    B             6         30
5   08    B             9         50
6   10    A             2         20
7   09    D             1         30
8   08    C             3         50
9   08    E             2         50
10  09    A             7         30
```

I have also created decision variables i.e. x0, x1, x2,..... xn for each row of the above input data set as above using loop statements as below;

```
decision_variables = []
for rownum, row in df_long.iterrows():
    variable = str('x' + str(rownum))
    variable = pulp.LpVariable(str(variable), lowBound = 0, cat= 'Integer') 
    decision_variables.append(variable)
```

> My actual question..

I want to be able to loop through the pandas dataframe to find all the **TaskFrequency** that happened at a specific hour and then multiply each TaskFrequency by the respective decision variable for each row - the whole expression should be less than or equal to the **TotalTaskatSpecificHour** for a specific hour 
e.g. an expression like this for Hour 10 would be:

```
4*x3 + 2*x6 <= 20
```

> So far I have been able to do this:

```
to = ""
for rownum, row in df_long.iterrows():
    for i, wo in enumerate(decision_variables):
            if rownum == i:
                formula = row['TaskFrequency']*wo
    to += formula
prob += to
```

this gave me:

```
5*x0 + 8*x1 + 7*x2 + 4*x3 + 6*x4 + 9*x5 + 2*x6 + 1*x7 +3*x8 + 2*x9 + 7*x10
```

> I also tried this:

```
for rownum, row in df_long.iterrows():
            for i, wo in enumerate(decision_variables):
                 for x,y,z in zip(df_long['Hour'],df_long['TypeofTask'],df_long['TaskFrequency']):
                           if rownum == i:
                                formula1 = row['TaskFrequency']*wo
```

I just get 7*x10

> what I wish to get is the same expression but for a specific **Hour** instead of the whole thing combined e.g. 
>   for Hour 10 it should be,

```
4*x3 + 2*x6 <= 20
```

> for Hour 9 it should be,

```
8*x1 + 6*x4 + 1*x7 + 7*x10 <= 30
```

I look forward to your suggestions and help.

Regards

Diva

Answer (score 0):

you would want a return column * (no of hours), in essence you dont need to apply function row by row, but condense the df by groupby like above answer, or slicing:
I think groupby is a standard way to do it but lambda is a no brainer.

```
def fun1(df, Hours, prod):
   return sum(df[df['Hour']==Hours].apply(lambda row:int(row.name)*row['TaskFrequency'],axis=1)) <= prod
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will like to go through it row by row for my use case. Am not neccessarily looking for another column, just a function that gives me those expressions as I stated on my post.